# How to concatenate two collections in java in a lazy way?

Tags: java, lazy-loading, iterable, enumerable

I have two collections and I want to return an IEnumerable which is the concatenation of them. The returned enumerable should be lazy and should not modify the two initial collections (So, I do not want to copy the two collection into one and then return the result because that is not lazy)

The code below is an example of what I want to achieve in Java but written in c#:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> all()
{
    List<int> list1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
    List<int> list2 = new List<int>() { 4, 5, 6 };
    return list1.Concat(list2);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Java equivalent of the `C# IEnumerable<TSource> Enumerable.Concat<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, IEnumerable‌​<TSource>)` can be found in `Commons Collections: <E> Iterable<E> IterableUtils.chainedIterable(Iterable<? extends E> a, Iterable<? extends E> b)`. Look it up.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Apache Commons Collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/) method [`IterableUtils.chainedIterable(list1, list2)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/IterableUtils.html#chainedIterable(java.lang.Iterable...)):

> Combines the provided iterables into a single iterable.
>
> The returned iterable has an iterator that traverses the elements in the order of the arguments, i.e. iterables[0], iterables[2](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/IterableUtils.html#chainedIterable(java.lang.Iterable...)), .... **The source iterators are not polled until necessary.**

Or [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki) method [`Iterables.concat(list1, list2)`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#concat-java.lang.Iterable-):

> Combines multiple iterables into a single iterable. The returned iterable has an iterator that traverses the elements of each iterable in inputs. **The input iterators are not polled until necessary.**

Answer (score 3):

Here's a manual implementation returning an `Iterator`.

```
public static <T> Iterator<T> concatIterator(Iterable<T> l1, Iterable<T> l2) {
    return new Iterator<>() {
        Iterator<T> it1 = l1.iterator();
        Iterator<T> it2 = l2.iterator();
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return it1.hasNext() || it2.hasNext();
        }
        public T next() {
            return it1.hasNext() ? it1.next() : it2.next();
        }
    }
}
```

And you can get an `Iterable<T>` using that

```
public static <T> Iterable<T> concatIterable(Iterable<T> l1, Iterable<T> l2) {
    return new Iterable<>() {
        public Iterator<T> iterator() {
            return concatIterator(l1, l2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The Java equivalent of [`IEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx) is [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html), not `Iterator`.

Comment: @Andreas And the only method in `Iterable` returns an `Iterator`. Of course, I can expand my answer to add that.

Comment: And the only method in `IEnumerable` returns an `IEnumerator`, so what's your point? Question is asking for an `IEnumerable`, not an `IEnumerator`, so equivalent Java code must return an `Iterable`, not `Iterator`.

Comment: My point is that the extension is trivial. I added it to my answer.

Comment: Inputs don't have to be `List` objects, just `Iterable` objects.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is `Iterable` then a simple `Chain` should work for you.

```
class Chain<T> implements Iterable<T> {
    final Iterable<Iterable<T>> lists;

    public Chain(Iterable<T>... lists) {
        this.lists = Arrays.asList(lists);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<T>() {
            // Walks the lists.
            Iterator<Iterable<T>> i = lists.iterator();
            // Walks the list.
            Iterator<T> l = prime(i.hasNext() ? i.next().iterator() : null);

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return l != null && l.hasNext();
            }

            @Override
            public T next() {
                if (hasNext()) {
                    T next = l.next();
                    l = prime(l);
                    return next;
                } else {
                    throw new NoSuchElementException("Chain exhausted.");
                }
            }

            private Iterator<T> prime(Iterator<T> l) {
                // Prepare for next time.
                while (l != null && !l.hasNext()) {
                    if (i.hasNext()) {
                        l = i.next().iterator();
                    } else {
                        l = null;
                    }
                }
                return l;
            }
        };
    }
}

public void test(String[] args) {
    Chain<Integer> chain = new Chain<>(
            Arrays.asList(),
            Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3),
            Arrays.asList(),
            Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6),
            Arrays.asList(7,8,9,10),
            Arrays.asList()
            );
    for (Integer i : chain) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

You can also do similar work for `List<T>` and probably even `Collection<T>`.

Comment: Doesn't work if one of the lists are empty. --- Also, inputs don't have to be `List` objects, just `Iterable` objects.

Comment: @Andreas - Good call - fixed.

Comment: What about first list being empty?

Comment: what is the difference between your answer and @daniu 's answer?

Comment: @DiegoBecquer - This one will chain as many iterables as you like.

Comment: What if you call it with no lists? Anyone writing `new Chain()` without any parameters is of course an idiot, but remember, the varargs can be given as an array, i.e. number of lists can be dynamic, and the dynamic code building the array may on occasion find nothing to iterate, so no lists is a valid condition.

Comment: As an optimization, you could hide the constructor (`private`) and have a `public static` method, which can check `lists.length`, and return `Collections.emptyList()` for length=0, and `lists[0]` for length=1. That also takes care of my previous comment. --- Oh, and you can eliminate the `prime()` method by moving that code into the beginning of the `hasNext()` method.

Comment: @Andreas - Thanks for the feedback. BTW - There is no **requirement** to ever call `hasNext` on an `Iterator` even though it is certainly unusual.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon No, but since `next()` calls `hasNext()` as the very first thing it does, it doesn't matter if caller did, the logic of skipping exhausted iterators would be executed.

Answer (score 0):

If your inputs are lists then the class below `ChainedList` can wrap them.

I had to feed two lists as a single lazy list to JAXB Marshaller, but it doesn't work with `Iterable`. To create elements with `maxOccurs="unbounded"` JAXB requires the bean property to implement at least `java.util.Collection`.

The solution uses Apache Commons, but there's an equivalent `Iterables.concat()` in Guava.

[Up-to-date version & unit test](https://gist.github.com/basinilya/d4837a2098b4349d17b9ac4b57e7a95a)

```
import org.apache.commons.collections4.IterableUtils;

/** This class makes multiple lists look like one to the caller. */
public class /* NOSONAR */ ChainedList<E> extends AbstractList<E> implements RandomAccess {

    private final List<E>[] elements;

    private final int[] endIndexes;

    @SafeVarargs
    public ChainedList(final List<E>... lists) {
        this(Arrays.asList(lists));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public ChainedList(final Iterable<List<E>> elements) {
        final List<List<E>> tmpElementsList = IterableUtils.toList(elements);
        this.elements = tmpElementsList.toArray(new List[tmpElementsList.size()]);
        endIndexes = new int[this.elements.length];
        int currentSize = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.elements.length; i++) {
            final List<E> curr = this.elements[i];
            final int sz = curr.size();
            endIndexes[i] = currentSize + sz;
            currentSize += sz;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public E get(final int index) {
        final int partitionIndex = getPartitionIndex(index);
        final int subIndex = getSubIndex(partitionIndex, index);

        // throws when index >= size()
        final List<E> subList = elements[partitionIndex];
        // throws when index is negative or last sublist is empty
        return subList.get(subIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public E set(final int index, final E element) {
        final int partitionIndex = getPartitionIndex(index);
        final int subIndex = getSubIndex(partitionIndex, index);

        // throws when index >= size()
        final List<E> subList = elements[partitionIndex];
        if (subIndex < 0 || subIndex >= subList.size()) {
            // a sublist may throw unsupported even when index OOB
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        return subList.set(subIndex, element);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        // this may perform better with contained LinkedList
        return IterableUtils.chainedIterable(elements).iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public ListIterator<E> listIterator(final int index) {
        // indexOf, lastIndexOf, equals, removeRange, subList
        // call this method and for non-RandomAccess lists
        // the default implementation is slow
        // T O D O: implement LazyListIteratorChain similar to
        // org.apache.commons.collections4.iterators.LazyIteratorChain
        for (final List<E> subList : elements) {
            if (!(subList instanceof RandomAccess)) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                    "Not RandomAccess: " + subList.getClass().getName());
            }
        }
        return super.listIterator(index);
    }

    /**
     * @return negative value when {@code index} is negative
     */
    private int getSubIndex(final int partitionIndex, final int index) {
        return index - (partitionIndex == 0 ? 0 : endIndexes[partitionIndex - 1]);
    }

    private int getPartitionIndex(final int index) {
        int location = Arrays.binarySearch(endIndexes, index);
        if (location < 0) {
            location = (~location) - 1;
        }
        return location + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return endIndexes.length == 0 ? 0 : endIndexes[endIndexes.length - 1];
    }
}
```